# Android app not updating content

Tags: bug, android-app, specific-question

I used the Android app to edit [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51106126/65863) that I had previously posted on Stack Overflow for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086754/). But the app is not displaying the updated content, even though I can see it OK on the Stack Overflow website.

I tried pulling down the screen page to refresh it, I tried stopping and restarting the app, but the old content is still being displayed.

**Update**: eventually, the app finally caught up with the new content on that page. But this is the first time I've seen it not update when I asked it to.